# Java embedded applet page security, how to meet requirements?

Tags: java, security, connection, localhost

If I have an applet embedded in a webpage and I want it to connect to server side software (also written in Java) how can I do this properly on a windows machine running local host? Would I have to run the java application from within the `localhost` directory and access the applet HTML from a browser (i.e. `localhost/applet.html`)?

From what I understand if you don't have everything setup correctly you won't be able to connect because of Java's security requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to run a webserver (a [very simple one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_web_servers) will do) and access the page with the applet through that.